# GLM with one categorical and one continuous variable

Tags: regression, glm, model-fitting

I try to fit a GLM to my data, I have two continuous and one categorical variable.
[Structure of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2aM2.jpg)
[Data summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItKQU.jpg)

I would like to test the relationship between the amount of biomass (mean_biom variable) and CV% of the biomass (biom_cv) and how is it affected by the habitat type of the vegetation.

I set up the following model:
glm1<-glm(biom_cv~mean_biom+habitat,data=data)

My questions are the followings:

1. Is GLM appropriate for this type of question (because of the categorical variable)?
2. Which family and link function should I choose?

Thank you for your answers!